# Block macros from running in Office files from the Internet for host

Tags: vba, active-directory, registry, ms-office

I am looking into blocking macros from files that were downloaded from the internet, and found the following registry that is in charge of it:

> HKCU:\software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\powerpoint\security\blockcontentexecutionfrominternet

(And of course the same path for the other office programs just replacing the word "powerpoint" with the respective program.)

I wanted to block the macros for every user on the host and so tried to edit the value of:

> HKLM:\software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\powerpoint\security\blockcontentexecutionfrominternet

But that proved ineffective.
(I don't want to go over every user in HKU and set for it specifically, because there could always be a new user who I hadn't set the registry for, that will be able to download and run a macro.)

Is there another registry or a way using code to block the execution of macros from files that came from the internet for a certain host instead of a certain user?

Comment: The way to go would be to use group policies in your domain controler to set these registry keys. So they are automatically set for every new user. • Another good idea can be to block macros in general unless they are signed with a trusted certificate, but that will require you to sign every macro you want to trust. Another alternative is to trust only macros in a specific folder (see trust center in office options).